# R: function applying multiple condition to a vector

Tags: r, vector, logic

Even though there are many questions on this topic I did not manage to find a useful one for my problem.

I have multiple vectors:

> test1
>       [1] 0.2 0.0
>
> test2
>       [1] 0 0 0 0 0
>
> test3
>       [1] 2 6 9 8 7 4 5 6
>
> test4
>       [1] 0.20 0.30 0.10 0.01 0.02

I wrote a function to manipulate the values using the following criteria:

- if sum(vector)==0, print "down"
- if sum(vector)!=0, and length(vector)>2 and vector>1, do vector*-1
- if sum(vector)!=0 and length(vector)==2 and vector>0 and vector<1, print NA

I would expect:

> test1
>       [1] NA
>
> test2
>       [1] "down"
>
> test3
>       [1] -2 -6 -9 -8 -7 -4 -5 -6
>
> test4
>       [1] 5 3.3 10 100 50

The function I wrote is:

```
tets.norm<-function(ratio){
    sum(ratio)->summ
    ifelse(summ!=0, ifelse(length(ratio)>2 & ratio>1, 
            -1*ratio, ifelse(length(ratio)>2 & ratio>0 & ratio<1, 
                           1/ratio, NA)), "down")}
```

The problem is that it returns me just the first value changed according to my criteria.

Any suggestion?

Comment: With `vector>1`, are you wanting all of the elements of the vector to be greater than one? If so, you should be using `all(ratio>1)` since `ratio>1` returns a vector of booleans (and `ifelse` might only be using the first element of that vector). Alternatively, if you want any of the elements greater than one, you can use `any(ratio>1)`.

Comment: You can use `return(-1*ratio)` and `return(1/ratio)` in your function.

Comment: @DavidArenburg well, not suggested but that's what I inferred from your comment, sorry anyway, I edited the comment.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do with `ration > 1` there. It returns a logical vector, for example `1:3 > 2` returns `FALSE FALSE TRUE`. Not sure from the problem description what you want with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tets.norm <- function(x){
  if (sum(x) == 0) { print("down") 
    } else if (sum(x) != 0 & length(x) > 2 & sum(x) > 1) { print(x*-1) 
       } else if (sum(x) != 0 & length(x) > 2 & sum(x) < 1) { print(1/x)
          } else if (sum(x) != 0 & length(x) == 2 & sum(x) > 0 & sum(x) < 1) print(NA)
  }
tets.norm(test1)
## [1] NA
tets.norm(test2)
## [1] "down"
tets.norm(test3)
## [1] -2 -6 -9 -8 -7 -4 -5 -6
tets.norm(test4)
## [1]   5.000000   3.333333  10.000000 100.000000  50.000000
```

Comment: thanks very much for the help! I'm adjusting my script using you advice. However I have and odd error message for if: `In if (sum(ratio) != 0 & ratio > 1) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`. Any idea what's the reason?

Comment: You can't use `ratio > 1` as is, either do it `sum(ratio)` or `length(ratio)`, depends on the context. Why can't you just take my code as is? Why do you need to change it?

Comment: Because this function is part of a longer script, and I have to optimize it.

Comment: So just change everywhere where it is written `x` to `ratio` I guess

Comment: I guess my problem is that I get an error when I put more than one condition in the `if` statement, and R tell me that `only the first element will be used`.

Comment: You can put as many conditions you want in the `if` statement. See my code above

Comment: I know that, but in my case it is not working properly. Anyway, I guess I managed to write a script that works.